# What choices do I have for localizing Bing News?

Tags: bing

Bing News (www.bing.com/news) defaults to a location that is nowhere near where I live.  Changing my location using the site seems to store the information in a cookie.  This is less than ideal.  Can anyone suggest an alternative way to get Bing News to display news for the city I live in?

Answer (score 1):

Try These Links:

www.bing.de/news

www.bing.it/news

www.bing.co.uk/news

...